# modify the style of sharePoint aspmenu?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

I am using this [website](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-%E2%80%93-part-iii/) to change the background of the menu and the dropdown menu, but it is not working. I see no effects at all.

can anyone tell me how can I apply the style to both menu and dropdown menu?
I am using Sharepoint 2013 by the way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since the link is for 2010 there is no wonder that it is not working for 2013 which has a totally new branding. Using a browsers developer tool to identify the different elements to style and thereafter write CSS that targets those elements, is my tip

Comment: I saw that it was SP2010, but I thought it might work for SP2013. thanks anyway for your reply and your suggestion